# How to change my image into a desired shape in python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-resizing

I am working on CNN model for MNIST fashion dataset. I have created a successful CNN model. But I want to test the model for classification for another image that I downloaded from internet .

My all train and test set is of the shape (28, 28, 1). But now for the image I want to predict I resized it into (28,28) and it made it into one channel of RGB using

```
cv2.cvtColor(load_img_rz, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Now the shape of image is (28, 28). I tried to input it into the model and its shows error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, 
found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 28, 3)
```

I think shape is the issue. So how can I convert it into the shape(28,28,1) if that is the issue.

And does CNN work better in one channel RGB than 3 channel RGB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful command for me in Deep Learning is the `expand_dims` [from `numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

```
your_image.shape
>>> (28, 28)

your_new_array = np.expand_dims(your_image, axis=-1)
your_new_array.shape
>>> (28, 28, 1)
```

You can play around with the axis parameter to get a better feeling of what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

since you don't include your code, i'll assume that you have a problem with your input layer. So, you need to specified the number of unit and inpt dim into your input layer first:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(X.shape[1], activation='something you desired', input_dim=X.shape[1]))
```

and so on

hard to understand what are you dealing with and what you want to achieve since you don't specified / share anything, not even the code.